# Touchpad and Wireless not working with Lenovo ideapad 330S and 18.04.03

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, touchpad, thinkpad

So I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.03 with legacy support because I was having problems while UEFI was enabled. Now I can't get the WiFi nor the touchpad to work. I've updated the Kernel to the most current version and still no luck. Anyone have any ideas as to how I can troubleshoot this? I've gone through three or four different threads trying their approaches and I've had no luck so far.

**`xinput` :**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse       id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**`sudo dmesg -xt | grep -ai input` :**

```
kern  :info  : input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
kern  :info  : input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
kern  :info  : input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
kern  :info  : input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
kern  :info  : input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:08/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
kern  :info  : input: PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:413C:301A.0001/input/input5
kern  :info  : hid-generic 0003:413C:301A.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:03:00.3-3/input0
kern  :info  : input: Ideapad extra buttons as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input6
kern  :info  : input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input7
kern  :info  : input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.1/sound/card0/input8
kern  :info  : snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
kern  :info  : input: HD-Audio Generic Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1/input9
kern  :info  : input: HD-Audio Generic Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1/input10
kern  :debug : rfkill: input handler disabled
```

**`grep "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" /etc/default/grub`**: 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

**`awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1; RS="\n\n"; FS="\n";  } /touch|mouse|synap/{print $0,"\n"  }' /proc/bus/input/devices`**:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=413c Product=301a Version=0111
N: Name="PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:03:00.3-3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0<br/>/0003:413C:301A.0001/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=903
B: MSC=10
```

Comment: are they being detected by the system when you run `xinput` for the touchpad or `lspci` or `lsusb` (depending on the wifi device connection). Let's start with the touchpad, run `xinput --short`, and if you see an entry for your touchpad pointers and its corresponding id, run `xinput test-xi2 [id]` and see if anything from movement to keypresses or taps gets recognized. if nothing is found with xinput, run `sudo dmesg -xt | grep -ai input` and post the output

Comment: I'll check tomorrow when I'm back in the shop. I'm pretty sure that I'm not seeing the touchpad but I can see the external mouse when I run xinput. Thank you for your help! I'll comment again in the morning tomorrow.

Comment: I'm trying to post things correctly as I'm new on this forum. I'm sorry if I'm doing this poorly. I've edited my original post to include some of the outputs I got from the commands you had me run. Thank you! As far as I know I can't see an id for a trackpad on this laptop. @barbar1234

Comment: Its fine, the pasting of terminal outputs has been a little disfunctional for me aswell lately, because when I copypaste your log into an editor it fixes itself. I see what might be happening. I will type it up as an actual answer:

Comment: @barbar1234 thank you so much for trying to walk me through this. Unfortunately the modprobes aren't returning anything even after those installs. I've again edited the post to include the outputs of those grep and awk inputs

Comment: Ok, in that case it appears that do you have have an outdated linux kernel packages, please run: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade ` and once that completes, run `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname-r)` and once that completes, please post if there is any change. If not, there will be one final step, but updating all the necessary headers might get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from your log output, it looks like Ubuntu is not detecting your touchpad, in that case run from terminal.

```
 $ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-libinput 
 $ sudo modprobe i2c_hid
 $ sudo modprobe psmouse
`
```

a reboot might be necessary, and if you see no change afterwards (after the reboot , execute the two `sudo modprobe` commands above again), please run in terminal:

```
$ grep "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" /etc/default/grub
```

and

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1; RS="\n\n"; FS="\n";  } /touch|mouse|synap/{print $0,"\n"  }' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

and post their outputs.